# Get build by pull request in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm having some trouble finding a way to find a build triggered by a certain pull request in Azure DevOps. I have the PR data, but I need to get the build that it triggered. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a build triggered by a certain pull request, you can click the following button in your pull request:

[image]

You will be redirected to the result page of the triggered build.

You can also find the pull request which triggers your build in your pipelines:
[image]
[image]

You can click on the pull request ID and you will be redirected to the pull request page.

Answer (score 0):

**First way :**

1. You can check the time in the PR
2. Match with a time of the build

**Second way :**
compare the things you have changed
it will come under updates

**Third way :**

So you have a PR - click on it
Under the title there must be some code - click that - it will take you to the commit

[image]

The commit code and Build code will match

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't know if that's the best solution because I can have 2 pull requests created at the same time and then there would be 2 builds with the same time.